# Segfault when doing syscall using GNU assember

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, system-calls, gnu

I'm trying to understand why `as` behaves differently than `nasm` when doing syscalls on the assembly level.  Because I'm a glutton for punishment, I'm using Intel syntax.  Here's my program:

```
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Hello world!\n"
    .text
    .globl  _start
    .type   _start, @function
_start:
    mov edx, 13
    mov ecx, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80
    ret
```

I assemble with `as -o prog.o prog.s` and link with `ld -s -o prog prog.o`.

But when I run it, I get:

```
$ ./prog 
Hello world!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

GDB is not particularly helpful here.  When I `stepi` on `ret`, it says `Cannot access memory at address 0x1`.  Which is puzzling, because the value of `ESP` is:

```
(gdb) info registers esp
info registers esp
esp            0xbffff660       0xbffff660
```

Why does this program segfault?

Comment: You can't just `ret` from your program, you need an `exit` system call. The `1` is the number of arguments (`argc`) which happens to be on the top of the stack, so `ret` tries to use it as an address with obvious consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it never exits properly. `_start` doesn't have a parent stack frame, so returning from it will cause a crash.

You can return from `main` to have the standard library's `_start` implementation call `exit` for you, but if you're writing your own `_start`, you need to call `exit` yourself, as there's no parent stack frame to return to.

Comment: @DanBarowy Mostly copied? I'm venturing the mostly may be the problem. If `ret` was working then `_start` wouldn't be the entry point, `main` would be. And the way you link it would be different since you need the _C_ runtime. What page/example in the book did you mostly copy from?

Comment: My last comment is to a now deleted comment it seems ;-)

Comment: @DanBarowy I'd go a step further: that book is simply crap, and should be discarded. It reads like it was written for DOS programmers, then hastily adapted to Linux at the last minute. (And many of the Linux details are seriously outdated, as the book was published in 2000…)

Comment: Also, a hilarious detail: `edlinas`, the "no.1 Linux x86 hands-on assembler development simulator" (according to the cover, at least) is actually a QBasic program, and can only be run under DOS.

Comment: Yes @MichaelPetch and @duskwuff, I realized that I had replaced `main` with `_start` after I posted the comment, which lead to the aha moment where I realized that _I_ was the idiot here.  So I deleted the comment.